# Estoy tratando de sacar la posición en android, pero se me cierra la app al probarla

Tags: java, android, gps

```
package proyecto.frog.manuel.victor.frog;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Objects Declarations
    LocationManager locationManager;
    Switch switchMode;
    Spinner spinnerProject, spinnerActivity;
    TextView textActivity, textProject;

    //TEST TO GPS
    TextView longitudeValueNetwork, latitudeValueNetwork;
    TextView longitudeValueGPS, latitudeValueGPS;
    TextView longitudeValueBest, latitudeValueBest;

    //Variables Declarations
    double longitudeBest, latitudeBest;
    double longitudeGPS, latitudeGPS;
    double longitudeNetwork, latitudeNetwork;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @SuppressLint({"WrongConstant", "MissingPermission"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        switchMode = findViewById(R.id.switchModo);
        spinnerProject = findViewById(R.id.spinnerProyecto);
        spinnerActivity = findViewById(R.id.spinnerActividad);
        textActivity = findViewById(R.id.textViewA);
        textProject = findViewById(R.id.textViewP);
        //TEST
        longitudeValueGPS = findViewById(R.id.text1);
        latitudeValueGPS = findViewById(R.id.text2);
        longitudeValueNetwork = findViewById(R.id.text3);
        latitudeValueNetwork = findViewById(R.id.text4);
        longitudeValueBest = findViewById(R.id.text5);
        latitudeValueBest = findViewById(R.id.text6);

        checkChangesSwicth();
    }

    public void checkChangesSwicth() {
        //Attach a listener to check for changes in state
        switchMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked && checkLocation()) {
                    //Objects are enabled
                    toggleGPSUpdates();
                    textActivity.setEnabled(true);
                    textProject.setEnabled(true);
                    spinnerProject.setEnabled(true);
                    spinnerActivity.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    //Objects are disabled
                    textActivity.setEnabled(false);
                    textProject.setEnabled(false);
                    spinnerProject.setEnabled(false);
                    spinnerActivity.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
        //Check the current state before we display the screen
        if (switchMode.isChecked()) {
        } else {
            //Objects are disabled
            textActivity.setEnabled(false);
            textProject.setEnabled(false);
            spinnerProject.setEnabled(false);
            spinnerActivity.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    private boolean checkLocation(){
        //Method that validates if the gps is on
        if(!isLocationEnabled()){
            showAlert();
        }
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert(){
        // Method that shows the alert if the gps is off
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Su ubicación esta desactivada.\nPor favor active su ubicación ")
                .setPositiveButton("Configurar ubicación", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        finishAffinity();
                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    public void toggleGPSUpdates(){
        if(!checkLocation()){
            return;
        }
        if(!switchMode.isChecked()){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerGPS);
        } else {
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Entro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2 * 20 * 1000, 10, locationListenerGPS);
        }
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitudeGPS = location.getLongitude();
            latitudeGPS = location.getLatitude();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    longitudeValueGPS.setText(longitudeGPS + "");
                    latitudeValueGPS.setText(latitudeGPS + "");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GPS Provider update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error que se muestra en el LogCat, agrega que version de OS usas, revisa [ask], trata de agregar más datos, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Parece poder utilizar el locationManager necesitas incluir los permisos en el Manifest.xml y después pedir los permisos en el metodo onCreate del MainActivity.
Añade esto al manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Y añade esto en el onCreate:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Requiere permisos para Android 6.0
    Log.e("Location", "No se tienen permisos necesarios!, se requieren.");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 225);
    return;
}else{
    Log.i("Location", "Permisos necesarios OK!.");
    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) mlocListener);
}
```

Esto último hará que le salte una alerta al usuario para que de los permisos necesarios.

Comment: ¿Como sabes que son los permisos si el usuario no ha agregado esa información}?

Comment: Porque los permisos se piden en el onCreate y en este caso no aparecen. Además creo que antes de que se editara la pregunta, estaba puesto el error que le daba al usuario del manifest.

Comment: Si tiene os menor a 6 no son necesarios y además el OP ya tiene esto que comentas en su código. Nunca ha agregado ningún mensaje de error. Hay que requerir información al usuario, la razón de cierre de aplicación puede ser por diversas causas.